Delayed Validation of Testcase due to application batch job
I have a test where I have to wait for 5 whole minutes to validate a status change. But, It is not right to wait that long in an automation execution. I am thinking if there is a way where i can make this test run as 1st testcase till that step, and then let all other testcases of same class run, then come back to this testcase and validate that status change.
I am unsure if this is a right solution and if yes, I do not understand how exactly I should implement it.
Edit:
Added a block of code to better convey what I think to do with this requirement.
@BeforeMethod(alwaysRun = true)
public void setup(){
//pre-requisite steps//
}

@Test( groups = "DelayedValidation"){
//steps to make that change
//This is where the application takes about 5 mins to change the status//
Assert.assertEquals(getStatusText(),"Done","Status is not changed")

}

@AfterMethod((alwaysRun = true)
public void cleanUp(){
//logout steps//
}

My logic :
@Test(groups ="DelayedValidation"){
//steps to make that change

// some logic to halt this test case and run other testcases in this class

}

@AfterMethod
public void runValidation(onlyForGroups = "DelayedValidation"){
//checks the status change after 5 mins or when all testcases are completed.
}


Disable the automatic launch of the job for this. But there is very little information here to be really helpful and answer your question.

Can you please tell me what information you might need to better analyse my query?

@Priya - TestNG is NOT going to block all test execution because one test method had a busy wait (a while loop, which sleeps for x units of time, checks for a state and if the state matches the expected state, exits the loop, else continues to sleep and check) in it. So you can very well build the busy loop that looks for your state within your test. As long as there are no other test methods that depend on this test method, TestNG will automatically take care of executing everything else while this test waits for the state change to happen
